# How to use resources bundle from parent project in child project (Maven + JSF)

Tags: maven, jsf, resourcebundle

I have a multi module Maven project, and in the parent project I put some properties file for the I18N purpose, in the folder src/main/resources. The reason for putting resources in parent project is that I would like to share them with all of my child projects. And in one of my child project which is JSF project, I would like to access to these properties file to configure the resource bundle for JSF pages which look like:

```
    <application>

        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>props</base-name>
            <var>variable</var>
        </resource-bundle>

    </application>
```

where props is the properties file name which located in my parent project, but I am not able to access it from my child project. Does anyone have an idea how can I access the resources from parent project in child project? Thank you all!

Comment: Instead of using parent-child structure, why don't you build a library (just a jar project) and add them as a dependency? It seems it suits better for this case.

Comment: ah ok thank you so much Biker!